# To Get the SQL Query_Hash in powershell

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, powershell

I am trying to execute the below powershell script to collect the SQL query_hash to use them in the next SQL queries but the output contains some random numbers instead of a query_hash like "query_hash : {39, 0, 2, 205...}" please help me.

```
$params = @{
    'Database' = 'Database name'
    'ServerInstance' =  'servername'
    'Username' = 'username'
    'Password' = 'pass'
    'OutputSqlErrors' = $true
}

$sqlcmd= "
SELECT TOP 2
    GETDATE() runtime, *
FROM (SELECT query_stats.query_hash, SUM(query_stats.cpu_time) 'Total_Request_Cpu_Time_Ms', SUM(logical_reads) 'Total_Request_Logical_Reads', MIN(start_time) 'Earliest_Request_start_Time', COUNT(*) 'Number_Of_Requests', SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(MIN(query_stats.statement_text), CHAR(10), ' '), CHAR(13), ' '), 1, 256) AS" + '"Statement_Text" '+"
    FROM (SELECT req.*, SUBSTRING(ST.text, (req.statement_start_offset / 2)+1, ((CASE statement_end_offset WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(ST.text)ELSE req.statement_end_offset END-req.statement_start_offset)/ 2)+1) AS statement_text
        FROM sys.dm_exec_requests AS req
                CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(req.sql_handle) AS ST ) AS query_stats
    GROUP BY query_hash) AS t
ORDER BY Total_Request_Cpu_Time_Ms DESC;"

$sql= Invoke-Sqlcmd -query $sqlcmd @params -MaxCharLength 999999
```

Comment: It ***is*** a bunch of random digits, it's just `binary(8)`. Either format it into `varchar`, or use some form of `SqlCommand` in Powershell to send the query direct, not via sqlcmd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can carry out a conversion to `VARCHAR` in the SQL statement itself and then no further work in the Powershell code is required:

```
$sqlcmd= "
SELECT  TOP 2
        GETDATE() runtime, *
FROM    (
            SELECT 
                /* note the change to the line below */
                convert(VARCHAR(50), query_stats.query_hash, 1) as query_hash, 
                SUM(query_stats.cpu_time) 'Total_Request_Cpu_Time_Ms', 
                SUM(logical_reads) 'Total_Request_Logical_Reads', 
                MIN(start_time) 'Earliest_Request_start_Time', 
                COUNT(*) 'Number_Of_Requests', 
                SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(MIN(query_stats.statement_text), CHAR(10), ' '), CHAR(13), ' '), 1, 256) AS 'Statement_Text'
            FROM (
                    SELECT  req.*, 
                            SUBSTRING(ST.text, (req.statement_start_offset / 2)+1, ((CASE statement_end_offset WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(ST.text)ELSE req.statement_end_offset END-req.statement_start_offset)/ 2)+1) AS statement_text
                    FROM     sys.dm_exec_requests AS req
                    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(req.sql_handle) AS ST 
                  ) AS query_stats
            GROUP BY query_hash
         ) AS t
ORDER BY Total_Request_Cpu_Time_Ms DESC;"
```

Comment: Hi @SEalre1985, Thank you very much that is helpful. when i try the below code it gives a different handle compared to SQL Studio. Do i need to change any thing ? `'$delta1 = Invoke-Sqlcmd -query $sqlcmd @params -MaxCharLength 999999 
$qhash = $delta1.query_hash
$delta2 =  "select convert(VARCHAR(100), plan_handle, 1) as plan_handle  from sys.dm_exec_query_stats where query_hash = $qhash"
$getplanhandle = Invoke-Sqlcmd -query $delta2  @params -MaxCharLength 999999 `

Comment: `foreach($plan in $getplanhandle)
{
$handle = $plan.plan_handle
$delta3 = "select * from sys.dm_exec_query_plan($plan.plan_handle)"
$saveplan = Invoke-Sqlcmd -query $delta3  @params -MaxCharLength 999999 
$saveplan.query_plan
}`

Comment: basically i was trying to capture the query plans and save them into a .sqlplan file and then use the same plan handle to perform DBCC freeproccahce and then again capture the plan and finally compare the plans. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.